# why am i getting a python indent error here in the django sample tutorial

Tags: python, django, indentation

i have this code from t[he django sample tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/)

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

# Create your models here.

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question

    def was_published_today(self):
        return self.pub_date.date() == datetime.date.today()
```

and i am getting this error: **IndentationError: unexpected indent**

on this line:

```
def __unicode__(self):
```

any idea what is wrong ??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My only guess is you have tabs mixed with spaces.

It's recommended to use spaces over tabs, with 4 spaces per indentation.
http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Do you have invisible characters visible on your editor to make sure that isn't the case?

*PS: your reputation graph says -6000 and it's really bugging me out.*

Answer (score 3):

Probably this is because you did copy/paste from the tutorial.
Pay special attention to the tabs and spaces.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks - this helped me. don't copy and paste from the tutorial!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it can be hard work with big files to find where error is, so you can install pep8 http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8 module and use it from command line

```
$ pep8 a.py 
a.py:1:4: W191 indentation contains tabs
a.py:1:4: E101 indentation contains mixed spaces and tabs
a.py:1:5: E113 unexpected indentation
```

Comment: Why you think that your response would help him? He already know what's error and which line.

Answer (score 0):

Python INDENTION will be responsible most of the time, to work correclty, use the editor or separate out the   **_*unicode*_(self)** with tab

```
      def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
            return str(self.name)
```